# hiding console when run in os.startfile()?

Tags: python, windows

I have a `.bat` file with parameters; I run it using `os.startfile(test.bat)`. Is there a way to hide its console? I tried using `subprocess`, it works well but when I close the parent program the `subprocess` that was compiled using `py2exe` console mode closes too.

```
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags=1
info.wShowWindow=0 
subprocess.Popen(test.bat,startupinfo=info)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `shell=True` and `creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE` with `subprocess.Popen`. This worked for me

```
subprocess.Popen(['test.bat'], shell=True, creationflags=subprocess.SW_HIDE)
```

In some releases of Python, `SW_HIDE` is not available in `subprocess` module. In that case, you may have to use `_subprocess.SW_HIDE`

Comment: thx Imran, sorry for the late reply. It works :) i just need to import _subprocess. thx again!