# Python making cmd invisible when using the os.system

Tags: python, cmd, execute, ping

I found out that i could ping a system on python by typing

```
os.system('ping ip')
```

but when i execute it, it shows cmd.
My question is, how do i ping someone on python without showing the  cmd?

Comment: when you say ping someone, are u just looking for a return code (1 indicating that the ping dint succeed and 0 if it succeeded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only a ping, then it would be better to use something like [ping.py](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2009/10/30/python-ping/).

In other cases use `subprocess` as suggested by @Sentinel

Answer (score 0):

Look at the

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

module.

It gives you enough options for controlling the output.

Or use standard bash redirection in order to send the output to /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [hiding console when run in os.startfile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313666/hiding-console-when-run-in-os-startfile/6313868#6313868)